# Below is code is for a soundboard attached to a 10-key. The sound loops when I press a key- how do I make it only play once?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Please let me know if I need to provide more info. This is for a soundboard setup- it's a raspberry-pi 4 with an attached 10-key. It works insofar as it plays the correct sound when I press a key, but the sound plays on a loop.
I see a section that says "Play an audio track indefinitely" but I have no idea if this is what I need to edit. Is this correct?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import sys
import vlc
import time

inputs = ['\'1\'', '\'2\'', '\'3\'', '\'4\'', '\'5\'', '\'6\'', '\'7\'', '\'8\'', '\'9\'', '\'0\'']
special = ['\'*\'', '\'+\'', '\'-\'', '\'+\'', '\'/\'', '\'.\'']

instance = vlc.Instance('--input-repeat=999999')
player = instance.media_player_new()


def loadPresets():
    ''' Get all the Presets in the current directory '''
    l = []
    for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        if file.endswith(".preset"):
            print("Preset Found:", os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file))
            l.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file))
    return l


def getPresetTracks(preset):
    ''' Get all the links inside of a preset track '''
    l = []
    with open(preset) as file:
        for line in file:
             # Need to get rid of those pesky \n's
            print(str(len(l)) + ': ', line[:-1])
            l.append(line[:-1])
    if len(l) < 10:
        print("Too little links. Cannot correctly populate.")
        l = []
    elif len(l) > 10:
        print("Too many links. Cannot correctly populate.")
        l = []
    return l


def isYouTubeAudio(link):
    import re
    if re.match(r'http[s]:\/\/www\.youtube\.com/watch\?v=([\w-]{11})', link) == None:
        return False
    else:
        return True
    

def getYouTubeAudioTrack(link):
    ''' Get Audio track of a link '''
    import pafy

    video = pafy.new(link)
    bestaudio = video.getbestaudio()

    # print(bestaudio.url)
    return bestaudio.url


def playQuick(num):
    ''' Make quick sound '''
    l = ['up.mp3', 'down.mp3', 'preset_change.mp3', 'startup.mp3']
    s = instance.media_new(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), l[num]))
    player.set_media(s)
    player.play()
    if num == 3:
        time.sleep(4)
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
    player.stop()


def switchPresets(readyPresets):
    playQuick(2)
    
    print("Ready to swap the preset. Loaded presets:")
    i = 0
    for link in readyPresets:
        print(i, "-", link)
        i += 1

    newPreset = input("What would you like your preset to be?: ")
    
    if newPreset.isdigit() and int(newPreset) < len(presetList):
        # Number preset. We're goood
        numPre = int(newPreset)
        print("New Preset: ", numPre)
        playQuick(0)
        return numPre
    else:
        # It's a character. Stop
        print("Invalid preset. Skipping.")
        playQuick(1)
        return None
        

def playTrack(track):
    ''' Play an audio track indefinetly. Also awaits response so it can detect a change in information '''
    from readchar import readkey

    # Load and add media file
    media = instance.media_new(track)
    player.set_media(media)

    # Play
    player.play()

    # Pause before getting the status, to update everything
    print(str(player.get_state()) + "          ", end='\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
    
    print(str(player.get_state()) + "          ")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    presetList = loadPresets()
    preset = getPresetTracks(presetList[0])
    
    # Start Up and initial setup
    active = False
    
    playQuick(3)

    import readchar

    keyInput = '\'0\''
    # Start Main loop
    print("Ready for input")
    while keyInput not in inputs or keyInput not in special:
        keyInput = repr(readchar.readkey())

        # Sanitize input
        if keyInput in inputs:
            # Play sound
            santized = int(keyInput[1])
            player.stop()
            active = True
            # print(preset[santized])
            if isYouTubeAudio(preset[santized]):
                playTrack(getYouTubeAudioTrack(preset[santized]))
            else:
                playTrack(preset[santized])

        # Special Characters
        elif keyInput == special[0]: # '\'*\'
            # Preset
            active = False
            player.stop()
            np = switchPresets(presetList)
            if np != None:
                preset = getPresetTracks(presetList[np])

        elif keyInput == special[1]: # '\'+\''
            # Play/Pause. +
            if active:
                player.pause()
                active = False
            else:
                player.play()
                active = True
        elif keyInput == special[2]: # '\'-\''
            pass

        elif keyInput == '\'x\'':
            # End case
            exit()
```

Comment: Just a guess: `instance = vlc.Instance('--input-repeat=999999')`. Maybe change or remove that option.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp - dude, this did it. I changed the number to 0. You are awesome.